# How can I dynamically decide on json items while converting an object to a string?

Tags: java, json, gson

I need to dynamically include fields while creating a json string.
Currently I am able to get the json string with all of the fields by using the `gson.toJson()` function. But in my project, I might need to avoid a field while creating the json string. Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Currently I have a class as below:

```
class XXX {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}
```

I use

```
Gson gson_obd =new Gson();
String Json_final= gson_obd.toJson(new XXX());
```

to get the full json string. But how can I avoid the field `b` while creating the json string?

Comment: hello teepeem.   the following is the code i used to conver to string. i have modified the question also. Kindly check and help me .   Gson gson_obd =new Gson();
      String Json_final= gson_obd.toJson(new ObdJsonString()); this is the code i used for converting to string.

Comment: Hi @Teepeemm, thanks for the information. iam new to posting question on this website :) . i have modified the question again. please check if that is enough. [ in the questino gson_obd is a gson object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an exclusion strategy and register it for the serialization process in the Gson parser.

```
class MyExclusionStrategy implements ExclusionStrategy {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
        //skip all b fields from the XXX class
        return f.getName().equals("b") && f.getDeclaringClass() == XXX.class;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and

```
String json = 
    new GsonBuilder().addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new MyExclusionStrategy()) 
                     .setPrettyPrinting()
                     .create()
                     .toJson(new XXX());
```

Output:

```
{
  "a": 0,
  "c": 0
}
```

I added `&& f.getDeclaringClass() == XXX.class;` to precise that you only skip the "b" fields from the `XXX` class. If `XXX` contains a `Foo` instance which as a "b" field, it won't be skipped.

Comment: this sounds correct.. is there a possibility to avoid any items if its value is 0? like, if the b value of the class is 0, it should get avoided while creating the string. is it possible?

Comment: yes the above one works perfect.  for more generic, i am using a LIST which has the excluded ones and iam using this list to decide whether its to be included or not ( eg:   public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
   return excludeitems.contains(f.getName());
  }   )

Comment: @JVN You can create a custom serializer. For each instance you serialize, check if the value of the field is 0, and don't add it to the resulting Json.